# Default redirection to www with IIS 7.5 & .Net mvc 3?

Tags: iis, asp.net, iis-7.5, rewrite

I haven't set up any rewrites or url redirects, yet if I go to mydomain.com I am redirected to www.mydomain.com.  Is there a default redirect that I'm missing, or is it something else?  This is my first experience with IIS so there is a non zero chance I've overlooked something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible its your DNS hosting.  A lot of DNS hosters will automatically create or duplicate your `mydomain.com` record to be identical to `www.mydomain.com`.  If you haven't set anything up on your web server I would suspect this is the culprit.